# How to use cursor fetch method by taking the advantage of PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I need to fetch every single dataset row with the cursor fetch method in PHP. But in modern times I would like also to take the advantage of PDO. In my example it is combined with a classically group changing:

I have the following tables:

```
create table profile
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    email char(50) not null,
    password char(100) not null,
    name char(100) not null,
    surname char(50) not null,
    street char(50) not null,
    homeno char(5) not null,
    group_id int not null,
    primary key(id)
);
create table usergroups
(
    id int auto_increment not null,
    name char(30) not null,
    primary key(id)
);

create table actions
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name char(50) not null,
    primary key(id)
);

create table group_rights
(
    id int auto_increment not null,
    action_id int not null,
    group_id int not null,
    allowed int(1) not null,
    primary key(id)
);
```

So, in the 3rd normal form.

And my PHP Code looks like this (at the moment it works, but I think I should take the advantage of using PDO in a better way):

```
class AuthModel extends BaseModel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function load()
    {
        $sSQL = <<<SQL
select `usergroups`.`name` as `group`, `actions`.`name` as `action`, `profile`.`name` as `user`, `allowed`
from profile
inner join usergroups on usergroups.id = profile.group_id
inner join group_rights on usergroups.id = group_rights.group_id
inner join actions on group_rights.action_id = actions.id
order by profile.group_id;
SQL;
        $arRightList = array();

        $pdo = $this->_db->getPdo();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sSQL, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
        $stmt->execute();

        $arRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT);

        $auth = new AuthList();
        if ($arRow)
        {
            $sGroup = $arRow['group'];
            $sGroupNew = $sGroup;
            $arActRights = array();
            $arActUsers = array();
        }

        while ($arRow)
        {
            while ($sGroup === $sGroupNew && $arRow)
            {
                if ($arRow['allowed'] == 0)
                {
                    $arActRights[$arRow['action']] = AuthList::ACTION_DENY;
                }

                else
                {
                    $arActRights[$arRow['action']] = AuthList::ACTION_ACCEPT;
                }

                $arActUsers[] = $arRow['user'];
                $sGroupNew = $arRow['group'];

                $arRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT);
            }

            $auth->addGroup($sGroup, $arActRights);

            foreach ($arActUsers as $sActUser)
            {
                $auth->setPrimaryUserGroup($sGroup, $sActUser);
            }

            $arActRights = array();
            $arActUsers = array();
            $sGroup = $sGroupNew;
        }

        return $auth;
    }
}
```

... And the class AuthList for completion:

```
class AuthList
{
    const USER_ALREADY_SET = -1;
    const USER_GROUP_CHANGED = 0;
    const USER_SUCCESSFULLY_ADDED = 1;

    const ACTION_ALREADY_ALLOWED = -1;
    const ACTION_SUCCESSFULLY_ALLOWED = 0;

    const ACTION_ALREADY_DENIED = -1;
    const ACTION_SUCESSFULLY_DENIED = 0;

    const GROUP_ALREADY_EXISTS = -1;
    const GROUP_SUCCESSFULLY_ADDED = 0;

    const ACTION_ACCEPT = 'OK';
    const ACTION_DENY = 'NOK';

    const LIST_KEY_NAME = 'list';

    protected $_rights;
    protected $_list;
    protected $_groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_list = array();
        $this->_groups = array();
    }

    public function addAction ($sAction)
    {
        if (is_callable($sAction))
        {
            $this->_list[] = $sAction->__toString();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_list[] = $sAction;
        }
    }

    public function addGroup ($sGroupName, $rights = array())
    {
        $iRetCode = -2;
        if (in_array($sGroupName, $this->_groups))
        {
            $iRetCode = self::GROUP_ALREADY_EXISTS;
        }
        else
        {
            if (empty($rights))
            {
                $this->_groups[$sGroupName] = array();
            }
            else
            {

                $this->_groups[$sGroupName][self::LIST_KEY_NAME] = $rights;
            }
            $iRetCode = self::GROUP_SUCCESSFULLY_ADDED;
        }

        return $iRetCode;
    }

    public function setPrimaryUserGroup ($sGroupName, $sUser)
    {
        $iRetCode = -2;

        foreach ($this->_groups as $sKeyGroupName => $users)
        {
            if (in_array($sUser, $users) && $sGroupName === $sKeyGroupName)
            {
                // User already are in the requested group, finish working
                $iRetCode = self::USER_ALREADY_SET;
                break;
            }

            elseif (in_array($sUser, $users) && $sGroupName !== $sKeyGroupName)
            {
                for ($iUserPos = 0; $iUserPos < count($users); $iUserPos++)
                {
                    if ($users[$iUserPos] === $sUser)
                    {
                        $iUserNo = $iUserPos;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                unset($users[$iUserNo]);
                $this->_groups[$sGroupName][] = $sUser;
                $iRetCode = self::USER_GROUP_CHANGED;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                $this->_groups[$sGroupName][] = $sUser;
                $iRetCode = self::USER_SUCCESSFULLY_ADDED;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $iRetCode;
    }

    public function allowAction ($sGroupName, $sActionName)
    {
        $iRetCode = -2;
        if ($this->_groups[$sGroupName][self::LIST_KEY_NAME][$sActionName] === self::ACTION_ACCEPT)
        {
            $iRetCode = self::ACTION_ALREADY_ALLOWED;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_groups[$sGroupName][self::LIST_KEY_NAME][$sActionName] = self::ACTION_ACCEPT;
            $iRetCode = self::ACTION_SUCCESSFULLY_ALLOWED;
        }

        return $iRetCode;
    }

    public function denyAction ($sGroupName, $sActionName)
    {
        $iRetCode = -2;
        if ($this->_groups[$sGroupName][self::LIST_KEY_NAME][$sActionName] === self::ACTION_DENY)
        {
            $iRetCode = self::ACTION_ALREADY_DENIED;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_groups[$sGroupName][self::LIST_KEY_NAME][$sActionName] = self::ACTION_DENY;
            $iRetCode = self::ACTION_SUCESSFULLY_DENIED;
        }

        return $iRetCode;
    }

    public function isAllowed ($sUserName, $sActionName)
    {
        $rw = false;

        foreach ($this->_groups as $users)
        {
            if (in_array($sUserName, $users))
            {
                if (array_key_exists($sActionName, $users[self::LIST_KEY_NAME]))
                {
                    $rw = $users[self::LIST_KEY_NAME][$sActionName] === self::ACTION_ACCEPT;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return $rw;
    }

    public function dump()
    {
        var_dump($this->_groups);
    }
}
```

I use the database connection class as singleton pattern. So,

```
$this->_db
```

is just a reference to the singleton which holds the PDO class object. By calling

```
$authmdl = new AuthModel();
$authlist = $authmdl->load();
```

You´ll get the ACL.

Comment: `'I need to fetch every single dataset row with the cursor fetch method'` - why?

Comment: because of the group change (it´s called group change when you got one ore more inner loops in cursor fetching stream which break on new group criteria). I can use fetchAll, but then I got 2 loops running over the same data. So, in my eyes this is performance waste.

Comment: Really? did you try to measure?